# How to Modify This Function to Get Most Popular Videos? (YouTube API v3)

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I use following method to get list of videos of a YouTube user.

First of all it finds the playlists of user channels and then it find the video titles of that playlist.

> It display the most recent videos. I need to get most popular videos.
>   How to modify this function to get most popular videos?

```
// Get Uploads Playlist
$.get(
   "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels",{
   part : 'contentDetails', 
   forUsername : 'USER_CHANNEL_NAME',
   key: 'YOUR_API_KEY'},
   function(data) {
      $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
          pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
          getVids(pid);
      });
  }
);

//Get Videos
function getVids(pid){
    $.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",{
        part : 'snippet', 
        maxResults : 20,
        playlistId : pid,
        key: 'YOUR_API_KEY'},
        function(data) {
            var results;
            $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
                results = '<li>'+ item.snippet.title +'</li>';
                $('#results').append(results);
            });
        }
<!--In your HTML -->
<ul id="results"></ul
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the videos.list method and set the chart parameter's value to mostPopular.

> [chart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#parameters)
>   - The chart parameter identifies the chart that you want to retrieve.
>
> Acceptable values are:
>
> - mostPopular – Return the most popular videos for the specified content
>     region and video category.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?chart=mostPopular&key={YOUR_API_KEY}&part=snippet&maxResults=4
```

For more information check this [page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos#videos-retrieve-most-popular-videos).